# Would questions about corpora-generation be welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/86/174) has been rejected from both Stack Overflow and the new beta site Open Data. It was suggested on the Open Data meta site that it would be more appropriate for Linguistics. I'm not convinced of this, but I'm willing to at least ask. In any case, there *is* a "corpora" tag.

(There's also a discussion on Meta Stack Overflow about its appropriateness there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179125/218334)

EDIT: The above link won't work for anyone who isn't a private beta member for another day or so, apparently, so here's the text of the question:

> I'm interested in doing sentiment analysis in languages other than
>   English; for instance, I would like to analyze tweets written in
>   Spanish. However, it appears that sentiment dictionaries for
>   non-English languages either do not exist at all or are not comparable
>   to the sentiment dictionaries available for English.
>
> How can I go about constructing such a dictionary? How useful, for
>   instance, would a standard Spanish dictionary be?

Comment: Hello Kyle, welcome! Thanks for asking, that's definitely appreciated. Uhm we cannot see the question, it's in private Beta. It says it will be for one more day, so either we wait for it to become public beta or you could paste the text of the question here in your Meta question so we can read it. I think that without reading it would be hard to effectively judge whether it's OK or not. :) OR you could explain it. From what I read, it sounds OK but yeah, feel free to add more content about it.

Comment: I've posted the text, as well as a link to a discussion on Meta Stack Overflow about where it belongs.

Comment: Sentiment analysis is definitely on-topic here. But your question was extremely general, basically asking for an introduction to a field or such. All Stack Exchange sites are geared toward specific questions with specific answers.